# c# asp.net make a get request on relational table with entity framework database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, get-request

I am trying to get data from a table with a get request with a controller. When I make the request with a normal table (TestTable) it is ok, but if I make the request with a relational table I get the fail message:

> "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'."

My controller (Mdata):

```
namespace ScThAsp.Controllers
{
    public class MDataController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Måledata> Get()
        {
            using (var e = new SCTHDBEntities())
            {
            return e.Måledata.ToList();

        }
    }

    public TestTable Get(int id)
    {

        using (SCTHDBEntities entities = new SCTHDBEntities())
        {

            return entities.TestTable.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
            }
    }
}
```

}

My Table for måledata is:

```
    public partial class Måledata
{
    public int MDid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BBid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Måling1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Måling2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Måling3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Måling4 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RegTid { get; set; }

    public virtual BuildBoard BuildBoard { get; set; }
}
```

My database looks like:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzhDL.png)
See link..

I think I mayby should make a inner join with the other table connected to Måledata table - I am not sure how to do that in a EF environment.

I have really tried a lot now - hope for an answer. Thanks

Comment: Disable proxy creation in the context.

Comment: Hi there Gert. Is this what you mean "this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;" But where to put it? Tried different places but the program will now allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Måledata` contains more data that you presented (it is marked as `partial`) and probably contains stuff related to EF. This magic stuff is not serializable. To avoid problem rewrite results to a plain object with properties you need. This object must be serializable (if contains plain properties and classes it will).

Comment: Hi Piotr - thanks for your answer. Can you be more specific to what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Building upon `Piotr Stapp's` answer you need to create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) for your `Måledata` which contains properties as your model, `Måledata` other than the EF properties. Use some sort of Mapper, maybe `AutoMapper` to map the required properties in your final response.

```
public class MaledataDTO
{
    public int MDid { get; set; }
    public int? BBid { get; set; }
    public decimal? Måling1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Måling2 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Måling3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Måling4 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RegTid { get; set; }
    //... other properties
}

public IEnumerable<MaledataDTO> Get()
{    
    using (var e = new SCTHDBEntities())
    {
        var result = e.Måledata.ToList();
        return Mapper.Map<List<MaledataDTO>>(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Abdul 
Thanks a lot for your answer.
I am quiet new to asp.net. This AutoMapper - do you know where I can find more info about this. Is this a program I have to install?

Comment: have a look at https://automapper.org/ and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions.
1) Solution was with Automapper (thanks Abdul). Installing automapper and a Using Automapper. Added a class called MåledataDTO : `    public class MåledataDTO
    {

```
        public int MDid { get; set; }
        public int? BBid { get; set; }
        public decimal? Måling1 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Måling2 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Måling3 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Måling4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RegTid { get; set; }
        //... other properties

}
```

`
In my controller I used the following code

```
           public IEnumerable<MåledataDTO> Get()
    {


        using (var e = new SCTHDBEntities())
        {

            Mapper.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<Måledata, MåledataDTO>();
            });
            var result = e.Måledata.ToList();
            return Mapper.Map<List<MåledataDTO>>(result);
```

2: In the second solution: In the picture you see the relations bewtween the tables - made in VS - but that creates a problem in the tables Get SET classes. The relation creates a Virtual object in the class - like mentioned before

```
public virtual BuildBoard BuildBoard { get; set; }
```

If you delete the relations and make the  public partial class Måledata like 
in this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ir4EIqxYXQ
the controller should then have one of two solutions:

```
            using (SCTHDBEntities e = new SCTHDBEntities()) {
            //this works
            //var knud = new List<Måledata>();

            //knud = (e.BuildBoard.Join(e.Måledata, c => c.BBid, o => o.BBid,
            //     (c, o) => o)).ToList();
            //return knud;

            //this works too
            return (from p in e.BuildBoard
                    where p.BBid == 1
                    from r in e.Måledata
                    where r.BBid == p.BBid
                    select p).ToList();
```

That was that 
Gorm